# Find a transformation matrix from one basis to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two basis's of space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$:
$$1,x,(x)^2,\ldots,(x)^n$$
$$1,x-a,(x-a)^2,\ldots,(x-a)^n$$
I need to find transformation matrix from first basis to second. 
I have written its matrix form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1&x-a&(x-a)^2&\ldots&(x-a)^n
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &x&(x)^2&\ldots(x)^n 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11}   & a_{12} & a_{13} &  \dots & a_{1n}\\
    a_{21} & a_{22}  & a_{23} & \dots & a_{2n}\\
    a_{31} & a_{32}  & a_{33} & \dots & a_{3n}\\
    \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
    a_{n1} & a_{n2}  & a_{n3} & \dots & a_{nn} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I don't know how to find that final matrix

Comment: Have you tried working it out for $n=2$?

Comment: Use the binomial development.

Answer (score 1):

We have by binomial theorem :
$$x^k=((x-a)+a)^k=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}a^{k-i}(x-a)^i$$
Then your matrix is a triangular matrix (which we name A for example) with coefficients :
$$A[i][j]=\binom{j}{i}a^{j-i},\ j⩾i$$

Comment: and why it's triangular?

Comment: Because from the sum above, x^k it depends only on (x-a)^i for i<=k, you see ?

Comment: Yeah, but i still don't get how you get this coefficients...

Comment: In your case we get transformation matrix from 1, (x-a),...,(x-a)^n to 1,x,x^2,...,x^n, but we from 1,x,x^2,...,x^n to 1, (x-a),...,(x-a)^n

Comment: Use again the binomial theorem to develop (x-a)^k, you will find what you looking for.